# DB2 LUW 10.5 - How to force DB2 Stored procedures to use latest stats for most optimized plan

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, sql-execution-plan, db2-luw

We see an issue occasionally. Stored procedure running a SQL runs very slow.  Same SQL when run from command line runs very fast.  It seems stored procedure uses a different path.  The workaround for us is to drop and recreate the procedure, after which it picks up the right plan.

Is there a way to execute a stored procedure with an instruction to regenerate execution plan at run time, so as to get the best plan every time.

Comment: db2 luw version 10.5.FP8 on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to recompile plans every time you call your procedure, as you lose the performance benefit of having the procedure in the first place.

When you *do* need to recompile it, which shouldn't happen too frequently in a stable environment, you can use the `REBIND_ROUTINE_PACKAGE` system stored procedure:

```
call SYSPROC.REBIND_ROUTINE_PACKAGE('P', 'YOUR_SP', '')
```

If you do decide that you want the plan to be recreated each time the procedure is called, you can set the `REOPT ALWAYS` bind option when you create the procedure, using the many ways [described in the manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0055082.html), for example by executing  `call SYSPROC.SET_ROUTINE_OPTS('REOPT ALWAYS)` before creating the procedure

Comment: You also have the ability to use dynamic SQL statements within your stored procedures (see the `EXECUTE` statement), so you can target just an individual statement rather than having to reopt all statements in entire stored proc every time.